# glm library ext.hpp compile issues (Xcode iOS)

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-errors, glm-math

I'm trying to include the `glm/ext.hpp` extensions header to my project. Whereas `glm.hpp` can be included effortlessly and the project simply builds cleanly, the extensions for this library yield tons of compile time errors.. for example, there are some auxiliary inline header files (`.inl`) with some macro definitions that throw the errors:

- int_10_10_2.inl : Semantic Issue

  ```
      GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER dword uint10_10_10_2_cast
          (
              glm::vec4 const & v
          ) //-> Expected a class or namespace | Expected ';' after top level declarator etc.
  ```
- type_vec2.hpp :

  ```
          union {value_type x, r, s;}; //Union member 'x' has a non-trivial copy constructor ..etc
          union {value_type y, g, t;};
  ```

What could be the conflicting construction (a hint on what files to analyze would be most helpful)? Has anyone else successfully include ext.hpp in an Xcode project?